# How to change the cell background color for child cells

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I am using [material-table](https://material-table.com/#/) for this UI.

I am trying to customize the style of a specific cell’s only when the onTreeExpandChange is true.

So basically I would like to have a different background color only for cells 2 & 3. I attached a screenshot for the desirable result. This will help me to identify only the child column header.

[image]

Some code example:

```
                  {
                        title: 'WEST',
                         field: 'west',
                        cellStyle: { textAlign: 'center' },
                        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#006EB8' }
                    },
                ]}
                data={[
                    { id: 1, group_name: '1', northeast: 'Baran', central: 'ddd', west: '3' },
                    { id: 2, parentId: 1, group_name: '2', northeast: 'Baran', central: 'ddd', west: '3' },
                    { id: 3, parentId: 1, group_name: '3', northeast: 'Baran', central: 'ddd', west: '3' },
                    { id: 4, group_name: '4', northeast: 'Baran', central: 'ddd', west: '3' },
                    { id: 5, group_name: '5', northeast: 'Baran', central: 'ddd', west: '3' },
                    { id: 6, group_name: '6', northeast: 'Baran', central: 'ddd', west: '3' },
                ]}
                onTreeExpandChange={(row, rows) => {
                    if (rows) {
                        // How to changne the backgroundColor of cell 2 & 3 ?????
                    }
                }
                }
                parentChildData={(row, rows) => rows.find(a => a.id === row.parentId)}
                options={{
                    search: false,
                    sorting: true,
                    exportButton: true,
                    paging: false,
```

Any idea how this can be done?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried looking at the data in `row` and `rows` with `console.log()` ? If row has a `.style` property you're set to `row.style.backgroundColor="#FF0;"`.

Comment: Yes, I did. Row actually contains the Object data so there is no style.

Answer (score 0):

Row styling seems to be only possible in `options` property of the React component, so you will have to keep an state at every drill-down you make adding the row ids to the state.

Something like this:

```
options={{
  rowStyle: rowData => ({
    backgroundColor: (this.state.expandedRow && this.state.expandedRow.indexOf(rowData.id) != -1) ? '#FF0' : '#FFF'
  })
}}
```

And you keep a `this.state.expandedRow` array on your state in which you put row ids at the `onTreeExpandChange` event.

Comment: Thank you Niloct for your help. I appreciate that. I actually workaround this bu using getElementsByTagName and changing the style via setAttribute inside onTreeExpandChange.

Comment: Well if you want my opinion I would advise against workarounds at all :)